# Axios or React saving my API requests/responses, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, axios

In an app that I'm making, during registration I am verifying that usernames and phone numbers aren't already in use. An issue that I'm running into with axios (I think its an issue with axios), is that it's saving the response from certain endpoints with usernames or phone numbers that I've already tested it with. I realized this when I deleted an account from my database and tried to register using that account's information. It isn't even making the request to my API, it's just remembering the response it had previously given (that the username/phone number was already in use). I tried deleting the node_modules and running npm install, verified npm cache, etc. Can't find anything to help with this, any suggestions? This is usually something that I would want to happen, but in this case it's rather annoying.

action creators

```
export const checkPhoneNumber = ({phone_number, country_code}) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: CHECK_PHONE_NUMBER});
    API.get(
      '/accounts/check-phonenumber/'.concat(country_code, phone_number, '/'),
    ).then(response => {
      checkPhoneNumberSuccess(dispatch, response);
    });
  };
};

const checkPhoneNumberSuccess = (dispatch, response) => {
  dispatch({
    type: CHECK_PHONE_NUMBER_SUCCESS,
    payload: response.data.in_use,
  });
  if (response.data.in_use == false) Actions.username();
};

export const checkUsername = ({username}) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: CHECK_PHONE_NUMBER});
    API.get('/accounts/check-username/'.concat(username, '/')).then(
      response => {
        checkUsernameSuccess(dispatch, response);
      },
    );
  };
};

const checkUsernameSuccess = (dispatch, response) => {
  dispatch({
    type: CHECK_USERNAME_SUCCESS,
    payload: response.data.taken,
  });
  if (response.data.taken == false) Actions.accountinfo();
};
```

Comment: are you sure you are not caching this items in your redux store?

Comment: `It isn't even making the request to my API,` so you checked the network tab in the dev tools and didn't see it there? Did you check if you have a service worker running (under application in dev tools)? What does `API.get` do?

Comment: API.get() is just an axios get request, I configured an instance of axios with my server's base url. I have my server's log open in another tab, I can see requests being made for numbers/usernames i haven't tried yet, but whenever I enter info that I've previously tested its not receiving the request. I don't see why it would be stored in redux, the state should get deleted on refresh and I haven't set up storage yet.